# How to give default value to TableColumn in Table

Tags: swift, swiftui, wwdc

I have this sample code:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    
    var name: String?
}

struct ItemTable: View {
    
    let items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(items) {
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Key path value type 'String?' cannot be converted to contextual type 'String'

I can solve using `\.name!`, but I'd like to give a default value instead (something like `\.name ?? "default"`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Change the model structure doesn't seem the ideal.

Comment: you can give a default value to name in Item struct like var name:String = “”,  instead of making it optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `TableColumn` init that lets you create the content in a closure

```
var body: some View {
    Table(items) {
        TableColumn("Name") { item in
             Text(item.name ?? "default")
        }
    }
}
```

or solve it with a wrapped property

```
extension Item {
    var itemName: String {
        name ?? "default"
    }
}
```

In the view

```
var body: some View {
    Table(items) {
        TableColumn("Name", value: \.itemName)
    }
}
```